# A divisibility conjecture related to the Ramanujan-Nagell equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

The [Ramanujan-Nagell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation) is
$$
x^2+7=2^n,
$$
where it has been proven (using non-elementary methods) that the complete solution is $n \in \{3, 4, 5, 7, 15\}$.

I've found an elementary way to reduce the theorem to the following conjecture:

**Conjecture:** If $r$ and $s$ are coprime integers, and $k$ is a positive integer, such that
$$
  (2^{k+1}-1)(r^2-2rs-s^2)=r^2+5s^2,
$$
then $k \in \{1,2,6\}$.

Are there results about factors of $2^q-1$ that might help me prove this easily? It may be a coincidence (*e.g.,* Strong Law of Small Numbers), but the $1,2,6$ made me think of [Zagier's famous problem](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Solution1.1.html).

**EDIT:** In case it helps, I can also prove the condition $(r^2-2rs-s^2) \mid 14$.

Comment: Are you sure that you have $(r^2-2rs-s^2)|14$, or is it the other way round. In your case, we have only finitely many cases, since then $(r^2-2rs-s^2) \leq 14$.

Comment: I'm sure. =) In fact, I should be able to prove $(r^2-2rs-s^2) \mid 7$, but I can't seem to obtain that.

Comment: But while that means we have finitely many cases (i.e., $r^2-2rs-s^2 \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 7, \pm 14\}$), that doesn't mean we have finitely many __solutions__, since each of those eight cases is satisfied by infinitely many integer pairs $(r,s)$.